# Javascript array not looping back to beginning

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm writing a simple card game, but for some reason this code below behaves very strangely...The turn functions is first called using `theTurn(0)`

`players` is an array of objects with player name and hand etc.

```
function theTurn(playerNumber) {
    if(play == 1) {
        $('#player').text(players[playerNumber].Name);
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            nextPlayer(playerNumber);
        })
    }
}

function nextPlayer(playerNumber) {
    if(playerNumber == players.length - 1) {
        theTurn(0);
    } else {
        theTurn(playerNumber + 1);
    }
}
```

For some reason I get player 0 then 1 then 1 again and then 0.

I've left out some of the stuff in theTurn...but this is the gist of it and the problem shows up in this simplified version too.

Any help with my faulty logic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does players contain ?

Comment: Is `play` used as a boolean or does it increment? This will currently add a new click handler every time `theTurn` gets called and `play=1`, try removing the click handler in `nextPlay`

Comment: seems like infinite loop

Comment: try break instead of  theTurn(0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually makes a little more sense... just add the click handler once, then set the player number as a data property so the `nextPlayer` function knows what it is without an argument.

```
$('#player').data('activePlayer', 0);
$('#submit').click(function() {
    nextPlayer();
});

function theTurn(playerNumber) {
    if(play == 1) {
        $('#player').text(players[playerNumber].Name);
        $('#player').data('activePlayer', playerNumber);

    }
}

function nextPlayer() {
    var playerNumber = $('#player').data('activePlayer');

    if(playerNumber == players.length - 1) {
        theTurn(0);
    } else {
        theTurn(playerNumber + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Trey...that seems to do the trick. I never knew you could assign data to an element...new trick. Awesome.

Comment: Gotta love jQuery.. I sometimes use `$(selector).attr('data-prop')` instead because it can serve a dual purpose as a selector for styling since it actually adds an HTML data attribute